# Android - how to hide button after few seconds of inactivity

Tags: android, button, imageview, hide

I have an app that downloads and passes image to ImageView. Now I need to hide button after few seconds after this operation when user is not doing any actions (eg. just looking on downloaded image). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Handler`

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        // hide your button here 
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, YOUR_TIME_IN_MILISECONDS);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! Accepting this answer because was first :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      nameOfButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}, 5000);
```

5000 is in milliseconds which equals to 5 seconds in this case.

**Note**: Do not use threads like Thread.sleep(5000); because it blocks your UI and makes it unresponsive.